# OpenXml-SDK: How to insert Plaintext with CarriageReturn/Linefeed

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, carriage-return, linefeed

Currently I´m having a Word-Template with an RTF-FormField in it, in this FormField I want to insert Plaintext that comes from a MSSQL-Database.

With this Method I´m setting the Content of any FormField in my Document(including my RTF-FormField)

```
public static void SetContentControlValue(this WordprocessingDocument doc, string name, string value)
{
    var main = doc.MainDocumentPart;

    var stdRuns = main.Document.Body
                      .Descendants<SdtRun>()
                      .Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value.ToLower().Equals(name))
                      .ToList();

    stdRuns.ForEach(c => c.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = value);

    main.Document.Body
                 .Descendants<SdtBlock>()
                 .Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value.ToLower().Equals(name))
                 .ToList()
                 .ForEach(c => c.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = value);
}
```

Unfortunately it swallows CarriageReturn/Linefeed

I tried to do it this way

```
var run = new SdtRun();

string[] newLineArray = { Environment.NewLine };
string[] textArray = value.Split(newLineArray, StringSplitOptions.None);

bool first = true;
foreach (var line in textArray)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        run.Append(new Break());
    }
    first = false;

    Text txt = new Text();
    txt.Text = line;
    run.Append(txt);
}
main.Document.Body.Append(run);
```

but unfortunately this breaks the WordDocument and I can´t open it anymore :-/

Anybody here maybe had the same Problem and has an Idea how I can insert the Text without losing the Plaintext-Formatting (CarriageReturns and Linefeeds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found a Solution by myself, you can use AltChunk to Insert Plaintext and not losing your formatting :-)

Here is the Code maybe it helps someone out who has the same Problem ;-)

```
public static void SetNotes(this WordprocessingDocument doc, string value)
{
    MainDocumentPart main = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
    var chunk = main.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.TextPlain, altChunkId);

    using (var mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mStream))
        {
            writer.Write(value);
            writer.Flush();
            mStream.Position = 0;
            chunk.FeedData(mStream);
        }
    }

    var altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

    OpenXmlElement afterThat = null;
    foreach (var para in main.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
    {
        if (para.InnerText.Equals("Notes:"))
        {
            afterThat = para;
        }
    }
    main.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, afterThat);
}
```